# Is there anyway to ungroup data in a grouped-by pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset that for simplicity I need to group by and aggregate based on one column so that I can remove some rows easily. Once I am done with the calculations, I need to reverse the group by actions so that I can see the dataframe easily in excel. If I do not inverse the action, I would export the whole list to excel which is not easy to analyse. Any help is gretaly appreciated.

Example:

```
Col1  Col2 Col3
123   11   Yes
123   22   Yes
256   33   Yes
256   33   No
337   00   No
337   44   No
```

After applying groupby and aggregate:

```
X=dataset.groupby('Col1').agg(lambda x:set(x)).reset_index()
```

I get

```
Col1   Col2      Col3
123   {11,22}   {Yes}
256   {33}      {Yes, No}
337   {00,44}   {No}
```

I then remove all the columns that contain Yes using drop

```
X=X.reset_index(drop=True)
```

what I need to get before exporting to excel is

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
337   00   No
337   44   No
```

Hope this is clear enough

Thaks in advance

Comment: `X.reset_index(drop=True)` does not change anything in your dataframe. It is unclear why you have it and what you expected it to do. Please include the expected result.

Comment: Sorry my bad I meant this:  YY=set('Yes') X=X.drop(X[X.Col3==YY].index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe converting to a set is a good idea. Here's an alternative: First sort in descending order by `Col3`, then create a mapping of `Col2 : Yes/No` and filter based on that.

```
In [1191]: df = df.sort_values('Col3', ascending=True)

In [1192]: mapping = dict(df[['Col2', 'Col3']].values)

In [1193]: df[df.Col2.replace(mapping) == 'No'] # or df.Col2.map(mapping)
Out[1193]: 
   Col1  Col2 Col3
4   337     0   No
5   337    44   No
```

Comment: that is wisely `replace`

Answer (score 1):

I am agree with COLDSPEED. You do not need convert to set

```
df['Temp']=df.Col3.eq('Yes')
DF=df.groupby('Col1')['Temp'].sum()
df[df.Col1==DF.index[DF==0].values[0]].drop('Temp',axis=1)


Out[113]: 
   Col1  Col2 Col3
4   337     0   No
5   337    44   No
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I guess I need to rewrite my code then. I am dealing with too many columns and need to modify your method to apply it to my actual data. What I provided was just a super simplified version of what I wanted to do.